# How to reset counter when new month using Python

Tags: python, counter

So I have been trying to make a script that save images by the month and using counter where every new photo added it will add a number at the end of the name etc `September_1, September_2 etc etc`

What I have created right now is:

```
import requests
import pathlib
import os
from datetime import datetime

client.counter = 0 
try:
    response = requests.get('http://clipart-library.com/images/pT5ra4Xgc.jpg')

    if response.status_code == 200:
        dirFolder = pathlib.Path() / "{}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%B"))

        if not os.path.exists(dirFolder):
           os.makedirs(dirFolder)

        while True:
            target = dirFolder / "{}_{}.jpg".format(datetime.now().strftime("%B").lower(), client.counter)

            if not target.exists():
                with target.open('wb') as ofile:
                    ofile.write(response.content)
                    client.counter += 1
                    break
            else:
                client.counter += 1
                continue

except IndexError:
    pass
```

and it seems to add folder whenever there is new month however the counter does not reset whenever there is new month and now I am here needing help on how I can reset my counter whenever there is new month?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Alright will do it right away :)

Comment: Have you got anything else in the directory where you're putting the photos, or is it just those files? If there's nothing else, it would be more efficient just to count how many things are in the directory, and then add 1 to know what to name the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've renamed `client.counter` to just `counter`, as you haven't defined `client` in the bit of your script you've shown us, so I don't know where it came from.

Assuming the *only* things in these directorys are the photos you've saved with this script, we can take a shortcut in working out what to call the file - its number is just one more than the number of files (i.e. photos) currently in the directory. This also assumes that you're starting your numbering at e.g. `september_1` not `september_0`.

I couldn't see anything in your script that would raise `IndexError` so I took that `try...except` loop away. I also tweaked a few other things to simplify it all a bit.

```py
import requests
import pathlib
import os
from datetime import datetime

response = requests.get('http://clipart-library.com/images/pT5ra4Xgc.jpg')
if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception  # or however you want to handle this

month = datetime.now().strftime("%B")  # save this as a variable to re-use it
dirFolder = pathlib.Path() / month
if dirFolder.exists():  # use this handy pathlib method
    counter = len(os.listdir(dirFolder)) + 1
else:
    os.makedirs(dirFolder)
    counter = 1  # we've just created this directory, so this will be the first thing in it

target = dirFolder / "{}_{}.jpg".format(month.lower(), counter)
with target.open('wb') as ofile:
    ofile.write(response.content)
```

I also saved `datetime.now().strftime("%B")` in a variable called `month`. This has the advantage of makikng it clearer when you use it later in the script, and also protects you from the incredibly slim (but possible!) chance of you crossing over midnight from the end of one month to the start of the next between when you set `dirFolder` and when you set `target`. If you did that, you'd end up with a file called e.g. `October_158.jpg` in the `September` directory (in this case with the previous file being `September_157.jpg`).

Comment: Wow! This seemed to be alot clear and also more smart than I did. I feel ashamed but I can just thank you for thhe help honestly! Was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ahh, no need to feel ashamed! I'm glad it was helpful. It's probably very easy for me to come in from the outside, see the whole problem/solution 1) all at once and 2) completely fresh, and be able to see a way to improve it. It's much harder to see and think like this when we've been "living inside" a situation for a while, and our solution reflects the way we've built it up step by step. I have the same experience where I find myself doing things that seem silly to another person because I've forgotten to change assumptions I made when I first came to the problem, which are now out-of-date.

Comment: Just keep coding, keep reading other people's code, keep asking questions and keep learning! 

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks for the words and I will continue of course!

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the counter after you created that month directory:

```
if not os.path.exists(dirFolder):
    os.makedirs(dirFolder)
    client.counter = 0
```